# VBScript CreateObject Authorization Denied

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, authorization, permission-denied, filesystemobject

When I run in VBScript `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` and `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` both return:

> Error: Authorization denied: 'CreateObject'. Code: 800A0046".

I am running they into `.vbs` not html from the browser; I have Windows 10 Pro (Cracked with [Microsoft Toolkit](http://freemicrosofttoolkit.com), It shows Enterprise) and I'm administrator (It's my own PC)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about vbscript in a html file hosted by Internet Explorer or vbscript in a vbs file hosted by cscript or wscript? They do not have the same privileges.

Comment: You're running cracked Windows, and you are wondering why something doesn't work??

Comment: i'm running Windows 10 Pro x64 (Copy downloaded from torrent) and I've cracked it with Microsoft Toolkit (Legit program, it's not really from microsoft)

Comment: Crack may affect this, Tell that if you have Administrator privileges? Is the error message `Authorization Denied` or `Access Denied`??

Comment: I'm the administrator and the message is Authorization Denied

Comment: So, didn't you try removing the crack and running script?

Comment: No, because i think that's a problem of the copy of windows that's from a torrent. A crack of the license in this case modifies only the license, the license's server and some windows defender things.